# Excel copy two cells of data from one sheet to another sheet if a third cell data variable matches the first sheet variable

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, copy-paste

I work in an insurance agency. We have Sheet1 with a column "Policy Number" (Sheet1,Column B) with all different policy numbers but need the associated column "Policy Effective Date" (Sheet1,Column I) and the column "Policy Expiration Date" (Sheet1,Column J) dates copied from Sheet2 "only" if the Policy Number (Sheet2,Column B) equals Policy Number (Sheet1,Column B) then copy/paste the associated Policy Effective Date from Sheet2,Column I to Sheet1,Column I and the associated Policy Expiration Date copy/pasted from Sheet2,Column J to Sheet1,Column J.

Example:

Sheet1

Column B       Column I               Column J
Policy Number  Policy Effective Date  Policy Expiration Date
123456789

Sheet2
Column B       Column I               Column J
Policy Number  Policy Effective Date  Policy Expiration Date
123456789      12/1/2012              12/1/2013

Comment: not copy paste - but place the @IF check in the destination cells

Comment: That sorta works. If there was a VLookup included somehow that might do the tick.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

> =VLOOKUP($B5,Sheet2!$B:$J,COLUMN()-1,FALSE)

Edit

For the time being “quick and dirty” (more complex formulae would do more work for you but I’m not sure it is worth the effort – unless you say so).

1. In Sheet1 insert a ‘new’ ColumnB, put =A3*1 in B3 and copy down.
2. In Sheet2 copy ColumnC and insert as a ‘new’ ColumnA.
3. In Sheet1!C3 put `=VLOOKUP($B3,Sheet2!$A:$C,2,FALSE)` and copy to `D3`.
4. In `D3` change `,2,` to `,3,`.
5. Select C3:D3 and double click on the bottom RH corner.
6. In `C28` and `D28` change `$B` to `$A`.
7. Select C28:D28 and double-click on the bottom RH corner.

Assuming there are no formulae elsewhere, probably best then to select each sheet and Paste Special Values over the top and then get rid of any surplus.

Note that all of this is based on the requirement being 'once off' rather than ongoing/routine.

Comment: This is as close as I can get to working but it still is not right. The VLookup works but it's not going to return the correct row within the column. This is because when the formula is copied down, the associated row is lost. UGH! =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B3,Sheet3!B3:B301,1,FALSE)),0,Sheet3!$I3)

Comment: Is there a way to attach an actual Excel spreadsheet to show actual data?

Comment: I've made this spreadsheet very basic but data/real world specific: http://www.csmworld.com/sig-ftp-72613/example_excel_issue.xls

Comment: We receive this data twice a month and there are several more rows (hundreds more) than shown on the example. If this were a one-time gig, I would not ask for help. However, this is currently very time consuming but required to import the Excel file into our management system.